# regex to group multiple words in a separate group

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to group pear orange or beef duck in a second group

```
category fruits pear orange
category meat beef duck
```

I tried

https://regex101.com/r/bmipyR/1

```
(category \b(\w+)\b )((\b\w+\b)+)
```

Comment: [`^category [a-z]+ (.+)$` and get the first match](https://regex101.com/r/tuX9eK/1), and then group them. It looks from your example you don't want to use `single-line` but `multi-line`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code doesn't consider spaces.

```
(category \b(\w+)\b )((?:\b\w+ ?)+)
```

handles this by making room for an optional space after each word.

Consider also using a multiline flag and anchoring the front and end of each line.

Comment: I don't understand why ?:

Comment: That ignores it as a capture group. It's purely for grouping, not capturing purposes.